# How to implement the custom user authentication in orbeon forms

Tags: liferay, orbeon, xforms

I'm deployed the orbeon war(Version 4.8 CE) file in tomcat and I have configure the persistence layer(Postgres DB). All forms are saved in the PostgresDB. When user hit the tomcat url **http://localhost:8080/orbeon** with my orbeon then **implement the user authentication** here.If user is valid then access the form builder otherwise throw error message.

Note user credentials are stored in the user table from the Postgres DB. User table look like.

username   password

sree   sree@123

ram   ram@123

Now only authorized user can access the Orbeon Form builder then create/edit/delete forms.

Some one help me how to restrict the user authentication for form builder.

**Note:** I am using orbeon forms are in liferay portal by using orbeon form runner(orbeon proxy portlet).

Comment: Your question is too general. Did you check the [Access Control](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control) documentation?

Comment: Yes I am agree. I need create a orbeon forms,only for liferay users. Is that possible please let me know. I am planing to deploy the orbeon.war file to live server but un authorize  persons also can create/edit/delete the forms. Is their any mechanism, liferay user only can create/update/delete the orbeon forms but not others users.